# How to change the window manager without the login screen?

Tags: dual-boot, window-manager, chromeos

I know, in general, how to change which window manager I use after logging in. I do this (normally) by choosing from a slightly difficult to find menu/list of window managers. Easy.

There must be a backdoor way, however, of changing the window manager. i.e., there must be a config file that stores the most recent window manager choice. What is it?

My problem is, I have a chromebook with ubuntu installed as a secondary OS, which runs in parallel with chromeos. (it's not bad.) When switching from chromeos to ubuntu, I am not presented with an ubuntu X login screen, so the opportunity to change window managers is skipped/not-available. I can't use the usual simple method. Where is the old-style config file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days of Unix, one would login to console first and run `startx`, which in turn reads your `.xinitrc` file.  I've done this on my Arch virtual machine by following [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc).

Alternatively, a lot of window managers have `--replace` flag. For instance, if you have installed `openbox` or `gnome-shell` you could do `gnome-shell --replace` or `openbox --replace`

Additionally, AccountsService sets most recent window manager session in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/USERNAME` file. For instance, I have:

```
[User]
XSession=gnome
Background=/usr/share/backgrounds/dream-hippocampus.jpg
SystemAccount=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu starts the wm with a custom lightdm.
You have three options.
1) remove lightdm so Ubuntu starts at cli, where you can startx or run whatever you want.
2) configure .xinit to run any wm you want to start in
3) modify the ubuntu lightdm or install another one thats more customizable